# writeable characteristic for android custom ble service always returns write permission zero when discovered

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating a custom BLE service on Android with a single characteristic that can be read/written. The code looks like this:

```
public static UUID MY_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("e0ec8d9c-5e4d-470a-b87f-64f433685301");
public static UUID MY_CHARACTERISTIC    = UUID.fromString("e0ec8d9c-5e4d-470a-b87f-64f433685302");

/**
 * Return a configured {@link BluetoothGattService} instance for the
 * Custom Service.
 */
public static BluetoothGattService createCustomBleService() {
    BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(MY_SERVICE,
            BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    // Current Configuration characteristic
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(MY_CHARACTERISTIC,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ |BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);


    boolean serviceAdded = service.addCharacteristic(characteristic);
    Log.i(TAG, "Building BLE service addCharacteristic returned "+serviceAdded);

    return service;
}
```

The call to addCharacteristic(...) returns true. The service itself is created, can be advertised, and the service and its characteristic are discoverable by clients.  Somewhere else in client side code, subsequent to a BLE scan that locates said service, the discovery code that runs looks like this:

```
            for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {

                serviceUuid = service.getUuid().toString();

                if( MY_SERVICE.toString().equals(serviceUuid)  ) {
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                    for( BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics ) {
                        characteristicUuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered() - found characteristic uuid="+characteristicUuid);
                        int cProps = gattCharacteristic.getProperties();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered() - found characteristic properties "+cProps);
                        if ((( MY_CHARACTERISTIC.toString().equals(characteristicUuid)  ))&&((cProps & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE)>0)) {

                         writeCharacteristic(gatt,gattCharacteristic,"configStringLiteral");
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
```

When this service discovery code runs, as I mentioned, it finds the custom service and the characteristic that were defined. Any values I set for characteristic properties show up properly at the time of discovery on client side. The characteristic shows as writeable.

The problem is that characteristic write fails always even though the properties say its writable.

Has anyone seen this?... or perhaps I'm doing something dumb and have been looking at it too long.

(BTW the device hosting the custom service at runtime is a Samsung Galaxy 7 and the client is a Galaxy 6 ...or vice versa, same behavior)

Comment: It seems you are setting up your BLE service without a **Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor** (CCCD) and without a **Characteristic User Description Descriptor** (CUDD). The CCCD contains the permission info.

Comment: True, does not have CCCD. I was focused on the characteristic I was trying to manipulate. I'll add a CCCD and see what it changes. Ty Markus.

Comment: While Samsung usually plays nice regarding BLE and lets you connect and possibly even read, a characteristic without CUDD and CCCD is inaccessible to older and/or cheaper android devices. You should always add both, even if they remain empty.

Comment: You don't need a CCCD if you don't want to use Notify or Indicate from the server.

Comment: Adding a CCCD and CCUD did not change the behavior. I am not interested in Notify or Indicate. I am creating a single characteristic custom ble service that my process will advertise when device A has no configuration. I have another process on another device B that scans for unconfigured A type devices. When a device is found I want to write config data to the writable characteristic. Based on the code shown, I have device A advertising successfully and device B can scan for A's and find them and discover their characteristics. However B cant write to A's characteristic found in discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Permission info is not sent over BLE when the services are discovered. Therfore the permission property should not be used for remote characteristics.

A client should inspect the characteristic property only to decide what can be done. If it receives an error saying for example encryption needed, the Bluetooth stack shall start encryption and then retry the request.

So, characteristic properties are the correct way to declare to a client what can be done with it. Characteristic permissions only tell the local GATT Server implementation how it should react to incoming GATT requests.

Comment: To clarify: The permissions I set when I created the Gatt Server implementation are not the ones being reported at time of service discovery...they indicate a characteristic is not writeable though it was declared as writeable. The discovered characteristic cannot be written to as the call always fails and onCharacteristicWrite is not called... which is consistent with the permission noted. Are you saying that the client-side behavior is not related to the permissions noted and this is coincidental?

Comment: Yes. When the client sends a command or request, the Properties are inspected; not the Permissions (since they are unknown to a client). If you see that the Properties are writable but writeCharacteristic returns false, please post your code. Are you sure you don't try to execute more than one command or request at a time (you need to wait for the on* callback before you send the next one) for example?

Comment: Yes properties are writable and the write fails. Code above adjusted to show proper context. There is only a single write operation once the writable characteristic is found in discovery... so there is not more than one request.

Comment: Have you tried to use the nRF Connect app (or similar) to see if you can connect to your GATT server device and write the characteristic?